# Replace unicode character in the string

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

A function which replaces an unicode character in a string:

```
void replaceAllOccurences(std::string& source,
                          const std::string& replaceFrom,
                          const std::string& replaceTo)
{
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> data(source.begin(), source.end());
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> pattern(replaceFrom.begin(), replaceFrom.end());
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> replaceData(replaceTo.begin(), replaceTo.end());

    std::vector<std::uint8_t>::iterator itr;
    while((itr = std::search(data.begin(), data.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end())) != data.end())
    {
        data.erase(itr, itr + pattern.size());
        data.insert(itr, replaceData.begin(), replaceData.end());
    }

    source = std::string(data.begin(), data.end());
}
```

Usage:

```
std::string source = "123€AAA€BBB";
std::string replaceFrom = "€";
std::string replaceTo = "\x80";

replaceAllOccurences(source, replaceFrom, replaceTo);
```

`replaceTo` may be get from some external conversion library, for example: [iconvpp](https://github.com/unnonouno/iconvpp). Normally I would convert the whole source using iconvpp library but I have a case where I need to convert only particular character, for example "€".

Comment: Does this have anything specific to do with unicode or is it simply a way of replacing one sequence of characters with another?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not worried about performance, you can replace all the manual work by using the `<regex>` facilities, which results in a considerable reduction of code to test and maintain.

```
#include <regex>

source = std::regex_replace(source, std::regex("€"), "\x80");
```

I would still keep it in a separate function to make it easy to change the implementation afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` objects at all. You can use the input `std::string` objects directly.

Also, the code in the `while` loop needs to be updated for the following issues:

1. Make sure to capture the return value opf `source.erase`. If you don't the iterator is invalid.
2. To avoid infinite loop, use `itr` as the first argument to `std::search`.
3. Update `itr` inside the loop appropriately to avoid an infinite loop.

```
void replaceAllOccurences(std::string& source,
                          const std::string& replaceFrom,
                          const std::string& replaceTo)
{
   std::string::iterator itr = source.begin();
   while((itr = std::search(itr, source.end(), replaceFrom.begin(), replaceFrom.end())) != source.end())
   {
      itr = source.erase(itr, itr + replaceFrom.size());

      // itr is going be invalid after insert. Keep track of its
      // distance from begin() so we can update itr after insert.
      auto dist = std::distance(source.begin(), itr);

      source.insert(itr, replaceTo.begin(), replaceTo.end());

      // Make itr point to the character 1 past what got replaced.
      // This will avoid infinite loop incase the first character of
      // replaceTo is the same as the character being replaced.
      itr = std::next(source.begin(), dist+1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `insert()` invalidate iterators?

Comment: Might have an issue with infinite loops.

Comment: @TobySpeight, yes, it does. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MartinYork, Indeed. Updated to address that issue.